# The type or namespace name 'Office' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ms-word, office-interop, class-library

I am getting this error message using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespace in C#. All references have been added but still getting this issue.

Comment: What code do you use?

Answer (score -1):

It is not clear what object/class you are trying to use when you get an error message.

However, you may find the [How to automate Microsoft Word to create a new document by using Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316384) article helpful. It describes all the required steps for automating Word. Also take a look at the sample project in C# - [C# app automates Word (CSAutomateWord)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomateWord-f422cae5).